# Editing httpd.conf prevents apache startup with Bitnami Django Stack

Tags: django, apache, bitnami

I've got Bitnami Django Stack running on Windows Server 2008 R2. Any change to the httpd.conf file prevents Apache from starting/restarting.

- Tried to include the virtual hosts configuration file (just as a test in its default state and with my own subdomains), breaks.
- Added the necessary Include line for my Django project, breaks.

When I comment out my additions it works without a hitch.

I realize these are two separate issues, but because they hinder Apache in the same way I included both cases.

I should note I couldn't find a solution elsewhere because the application log gives me nothing other than "Unable to Start Apache" and Apache's error log has no errors. I also looked through the Bitnami Django Stack and Apache documentation to no avail.